# PHP set dropdown list default value

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list in which options are generated by javascript like that:

```
<select class="form-control" id="which-year" name="which-year">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    etc...
    <!-- options generated by scripts.js -->
</select>
```

After page loaded, I will retrieve `which-year` (an integer number) from database and set it as an option in dropdown list above. Problem is I don't know how to add the `selected` attribute using `PHP` to those options because they are totally generated by script.
How can I do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For ex. If you want to make selected 2015

`$("#which-year option[value=2015]").attr("selected","selected");`

Comment: @BraveVN If you dont use an array to generate the list then this would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<option value="2015"<?=$row['year'] == '2015' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>2015</option>
```

Better to create an array of values and loop through that to create a dropdown.

Comment: I tried to add these php code into the js script, however, when the page loaded, it didn't recognize they are `PHP`.

Comment: Why would you add `php` script in `JS`? Use it with `HTML`. If you still want to use it in `js`, then use it like this: `var htmlcontent = "<option value="2015"<?=$row['year'] == '2015' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>2015</option>"`

Comment: my page extension is `.php`, the options are generated by script, after that, I retrieve data from db and compare, if `which-year = year_from_db` then I set the selected value in the dropdown list with `which-year`

Comment: This should help: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Comment: Looks like I must totally use JS to set the selected option.

Comment: yeah... you should either use `php` or `js`, but you can't use both languages in same script. It is a bad practice